# Why doesn't accept the Map constructor an Array of iterable tuples?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, tuples, iterable

I created a tuple type in Javascript that implements the `Iterable` protocol. Now it should be easy to convert to `Map`:

```
const Tuple = (...args) => {
  const Tuple = f => f(...args);
  Tuple[Symbol.iterator] = () => args[Symbol.iterator]();
  return Tuple;
};

new Map([Tuple(1, "a"), Tuple(2, "b")]); // Map {undefined => undefined}
```

Instead I have to do the conversion manually:

```js
const Tuple = (...args) => {
  const Tuple = f => f(...args);
  Tuple[Symbol.iterator] = () => args[Symbol.iterator]();
  return Tuple;
};

const toArray = tx => tx((...args) => args);

const Map_ = (...pairs) => {
  return new Map(pairs.map(pair => toArray(pair)));
};

const map = Map_(Tuple(1, "a"), Tuple(2, "b"));

console.log(map.get(1), map.get(2)); // "a" "b"
```

It seems as if `Map` only accepts an `Iterable` for the outer composite type, not for the inner pairs. What am I missing? Is there another way to achieve the conversion?

Comment: What design goal are you supporting by creating two functions every time you create a `Tuple`?

Comment: Immutability; avoiding the usage of `Array`s to store related data of various type (e.g. `[a, b]`). `Array` is a collection and hence should be of type `[a]`.

Comment: Immutability doesn't require that you create multiple functions per `Tuple`.

Comment: oh yes, you're right, it's church encoded. It doesn't have to be, of course.

Comment: *"it's church encoded"* Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map`'s constructor is defined as accepting any Iterable of key/value objects, where the key/value objects are defined as objects where property `0` is the key and property `1` is the value. It says nothing about allowing Iterables for the key/value objects. *(It might have been cool if it did allow them and define that it would call the iterator exactly twice, but...that's not what they did. :-) And it* would *be more complex...)*

If we look at [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-map-iterable), your `Tuple` would work if it supported the properties `0` (for the key) and `1` (for the value). For instance:

```js
// (Defined this way because you seemed to want a non-constructor)
const TupleMethods = {
  get "0"() {
    return this.key;
  },
  get "1"() {
    return this.value;
  }
};
const Tuple = (key, value) => {
  const t = Object.create(TupleMethods);
  t.key = key;
  t.value = value;
  return t;
}
// Usage:
const m = new Map([
  Tuple("one", "uno"),
  Tuple("two", "due"),
  Tuple("three", "tre")
]);
console.log(m.get("two")); // "due"
```

---

In a comment you mentioned immutability. Perhaps:

```js
// (Defined this way because you seemed to want a non-constructor)
const TupleMethods = {};
Object.defineProperties(TupleMethods, {
    "0": {
        get() {
            return this.key;
        }
    },
    "1": {
        get() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
});
const Tuple = (key, value) => {
    const t = Object.create(TupleMethods);
    Object.defineProperties(t, {
        key: {
            value: key
        },
        value: {
            value: value
        }
    });
    return t;
};

// Usage:
const m = new Map([
    Tuple("one", "uno"),
    Tuple("two", "due"),
    Tuple("three", "tre")
]);
console.log(m.get("two")); // "due"
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I created a tuple type in Javascript that implements the `Iterable` protocol.

Don't. Tuples have the distinct property that they are of fixed length and every element has (can have) its own type, whereas (iterable) collections consist of multiple elements of the *same* type. Of course JavaScript doesn't care about types (all arrays are heterogeneous), but you as a programmer should.

> Why does `Map` only accept an `Iterable` for the outer composite type, not for the inner pairs?

For the exact same reason. The elements are *pairs*, or two-tuples, represented as arrays (for lack of another data structure, and simplicity of not having to introduce one like they did for iterator results). They always have exactly two elements, accessible as `[0]` and `[1]` (they don't even need a `.length`!), and there is absolutely no reason iterate them.

Comment: I know that tuples are usually not foldable. I've only made them iterable so that they can play nicely with `Array.from` and `Map`. However, I didn't understand how the `Map` constructor works under the hood. Now it makes perfect sense!

Comment: @ftor `Array.from` also works with objects that have integer properties and a `.length`. I don't understand why or how you would want to create a `Map` from a tuple, though.

Comment: Maybe I am on the wrong path here. I thought converting from `[(k, v)]` to `Map k v` and vice versa would be a sensible thing. However, I don't have much experience with tuples.

Comment: Yes, it would be, I thought you meant `new Map(Tuple([k1, v1], [k2, v2], …))` for which the tuple would need to be iterable. For `Array.from(Tuple(…))` and `new Map([Tuple(k1, v1), Tuple(k2, v2), …])` all you need are the three properties `0`, `1` and `length`.

Comment: Sorry, no. I just assumed that "_accepts an `Iterable`_" refers to the inner pairs `[[k, v]]` as well. But why should it when the structure of these pairs is plain and simple and well known. I'll try to provide type signatures for my next question. Anyway, I've become accustomed to define them for all my functions. It has turned out that when I have trouble with expressing type sigs, I frequently discard the corresponding function eventually. It is a good indicator whether a function is useful or not - even in an untyped language.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const Tuple = (...args) => Object.entries({[args.shift()]: args.shift()});

const map = new Map(Tuple(0, "a").concat(Tuple(1, "b")));

console.log(map.get("0"), map.get("1"));
```